# I2C to FPGA to PCIe to HID

Tags: windows, drivers, fpga, hid, i2c

We have a hardware design in progress that is taking touch screen inputs and passing them along via I2C to an FPGA. The FPGA translates the I2C data to PCIe. The PCIe passes the touchscreen data to the processor. I am wondering how to get Windows to recognize this PCIe interface and deal with it like a HID. (Human Interface Device) It appears HIDs are typically USB. Can PCIe be recognized and used with Windows? Would this require a custom Windows driver? I have seen I2C to USB pSoCs that convert I2C to USB. We are trying to use the FPGA as a central point for simplifying and consolodating I/O but the tradeoff of simplifying the layout and parts may be overcome by the software development effort for custom PCIe drivers.

Comment: I think your Q is more suited to Electronics forum : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Roger Can you change the "title" of this post to a summarizing _question_?

Answer (score 0):

You should write a Function driver for your pci (fpga) card that will interface with the hidclass msft driver as a minport.
Efi@neuberger.co.il